# React testing: test that component renders child component

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, react-testing-library, react-test-renderer

I have a react component that renders a bunch of child components.
I am trying to test that this component indeeds renders these components.
I rather avoid Enzyme, so I am trying to use @testing-library/react and react-test-renderer.

I seem to be be able to get the child component via findByType, but I can't find any assertion in the library to check the element is rendered. I've tried checking for nullity but that doesn't work when the component is not there.

I don't want to use react-test-renderer's getByRole because that would be testing the role of the root element of the child component, and I think that belongs to the child component's test. I just want to test the child components are instantiated.

Am I approching this the wrong way? Is it not general practice to test a parent renders its children correctly? Should I be using snapshot testing instead?

App.tsx

```
...
return (
  <Navbar className={styles.navbar} />
  <Header />
  <Footer />   
);
```

App.test.ts

```
import { render, screen } from '@testing-library/react';
import Footer from './footer/Footer';
import Navbar from './navbar/Navbar';
describe('App', () => {
  let component;
  let instance;

  beforeEach(() => {
    // render(<App />); // Unsure if I should use react-testing-lib or react-test-renderer
    component = renderer.create(<App />);
    instance = component.root;
  });

  it('should render a navbar', () => {
    expect(instance.findByType(Navbar)).not.toBeNull;  ??
    expect(instance.findByType('section')).toBeNull; // Just playing with the null assertion here, this causes the test to fail
  });

  it('should define the footer', () => {
    expect(instance.findByType(Footer)).not.toBeNull; ??
  });
});
```